# Setting root folder of FolderListModel not working in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using FolderListModel to get list of files in a specific directory in QML.

```
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.json"]
    rootFolder: "file:///" + applicationDirPath +  "/Schedules"
    folder: "file:///" + applicationDirPath + "/Schedules"
}
```

This is working fine in windows. However, I'm having problem with Ubuntu. So I changed the code to this:

```
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.json"]
    rootFolder: applicationDirPath +  "/Schedules"
    folder: applicationDirPath + "/Schedules"
}
```

But this is not working either :( Even I have tried to hard code the path but it didn't help also:

```
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.json"]
    folder:  "/home/test/Schedules"
    rootFolder:  "/home/test/Schedules"
}
```

Any hints will be appreciated

Comment: What version of Qt? FolderListModel is part of Qt.labs.folderlistmodel, which (like some other parts of Qt.labs) isn't guaranteed to be forward compatible. Also remember that urls and strings may need explicit conversions.

Comment: @mzimmers Qt5.11 and 5.15 I tested

Comment: I guess that setting both `rootFolder` and `folder` confuses the QML.   The [qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#folder-prop) says uniquely: _The value must be a file: or qrc: URL, or a relative URL._  So you probably have to remove `rootFolder` or really set it to **root folder** and use `folder` as said above - as a relative url or using `file:`